# How to make a textbox mask for date and some custom masks

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying in a gridview for some template items to make some textboxes with mask.

For example:
[_ _ - _ _ _ _ ]  - So it will allow you to add 2 letters then it will move forward and you will continue adding 4 numbers

And for date :
[dd-mm-year] - So if I type the date I shouldn't add the character '-' .

I'm not so familiar with masks and if someone wouldn't mind helping , I'll appreciate

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this link

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

This control is available in `AjaxControlToolkit`

> **What is the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit?**
>
> The ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit is an open-source project built on
>   top of the Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX framework. It is a joint effort
>   between Microsoft and the ASP.NET AJAX community that provides a
>   powerful infrastructure to write reusable, customizable and extensible
>   ASP.NET AJAX extenders and controls, as well as a rich array of
>   controls that can be used out of the box to create an interactive Web
>   experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using jQuery?  Client side and very flexible and fast.

Here is a cool plugin I have used lots.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Thank you but I'm not familiar with JQuery and because I'm not I won't go with because I need to learn jquery and I currently learning c#

Comment: No problem, but trust me jQuery is a very valuable tool to learn to use.

Comment: this link is dead